# How to change from paid version to free version with subscriptions in iOS / StoreKit 2

Tags: storekit, swiftystorekit

I have an existing app on the app store since many years. Users had to pay to download the app. Now I want to shift to a *freemium* model by implementing in-app purchases.
And I want to be fair to previous-purchasers of my app.

I searched and read a lot about this topic and it is still intimidating to me, mostly because it always comes down to *parse* the **original transaction receipt** and "parse out" encrypted stuff like ["Original App Version Field"](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ReceiptFields.html) ... I was so hoping, the new StoreKit 2 offers more options for this very common problem, but couldn't find it.

So here I am asking: Is there a **more easy way** within **StoreKit 2** to retrieve more 'readable' data from the **original purchase**?

Any hint would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Apple:

> **Use the Original API to Support Certain Features**
>
> You may need to use the original in-app purchase API if your app depends on any of the following features:
>
> - To provide support for the Volume Purchase Program (VPP). For more information, see Device Management.
> - To provide app pre-orders.
> - Your app changed from a ***premium to a freemium*** model, or vice versa.
>   Use the original API for existing and legacy apps.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/choosing_a_storekit_api_for_in-app_purchase

So, apparently, there is no way to retrieve that information with StoreKit 2, at least as of now, with iOS 15.

Comment: This seems to have changed in the latest guidelines it seems. Only the first one (VPP) remains in the list you quoted, others are removed.

Answer (score 0):

With **iOS 16** and **macOS 13.0** you can do this directly with StoreKit:

```
import StoreKit

do {
     // Get the appTransaction.
      let shared = try await AppTransaction.shared
        if case .verified(let appTransaction) = shared {
            // Hard-code the major version number in which the app's business model changed.
            #if os(macOS)
            let newBusinessModelVersion = "2" // CFBundleShortVersionString
            #else
            let newBusinessModelVersion = "42" // CFBundleVersion
            #endif
            
            // Get the major version number of the version the customer originally purchased.
            #if os(macOS)
            let versionComponents = appTransaction.originalAppVersion.split(separator: ".")
            let originalVersion = versionComponents[0]
            #else
            let originalVersion = appTransaction.originalAppVersion
            #endif

            NSLog("original purchased version: \(originalVersion)")

            if originalVersion < newBusinessModelVersion {
                // This customer purchased the app before the business model changed.
                // Deliver content that they're entitled to based on their app purchase.
            }
            else {
                // This customer purchased the app after the business model changed.
            }
        }
    }
catch {
    // Handle errors.
}
```

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/apptransaction/3954447-originalappversion

Comment: This looks promising, thanks a lot. If it works, I will make yours the accepted answer. But I can try it only in a couple of weeks. 